# Sections are included in TOC, but not in the body text

Tags: sectioning

I need sections included in the TOC, but not in the body text for a PDF output; so when I click the section at TOC, it will jump to the related page [where section header/title is not displayed]. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

It's an unusual request, but the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package can help you here: use the `explicit` package option and do *not* use `#1` in `\titleformat`; `\titlespacing` can be used to suppress the spacing associated to the sectional unit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{-12pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

With this approach, all you have to do to recover the section titles in your document is to comment out (or delete) the `\titleformat`, `\titlespacing` lines.

Comment: Will this ensure vertical spacing of section suppressed?

Comment: @Firdews: it does now in my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `\phantomsection`. In the example, the words "Hidden Section" would be replace with whatever the name of your section is.

**Code/Example:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref} % needed for \phantomsection

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\lipsum[1-7]

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Hidden section}% <-- replace "Hidden section" with your section name
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `\section{I do not want you}` use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{I do not want you}` like in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{I do not want you}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually we prefer answering in form of [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/13304) so that others may easily test the proposed solution.